# Monoid as a one-object category... for monoidal categories

Tags: monoidal-categories

A monoid can be seen as a one-object category.

Is there analogous thing for monoids in a monoidal category $(M, \otimes, I)$? Can I form some kind of one-object category from a monoid in $M$?

Answer (score 10):

It is a one-object category enriched over $M$, see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category#InMonoidCat.

Comment: And then a standard way of getting an ordinary (one-object) category from this is by applying the change-of-base functor $\hom(I, -): M \to \mathbf{Set}$. This takes enriched monoids to ordinary monoids.

Answer (score 0):

A monoidal category is a one object 2-category